# Laravel how to do group concat from two columns using querybuilder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I got a params which is `projectname` and it accepts any string based on the column of my db. What I want is when I search a keyword which is like this `BEDOK`, then shows me the concatinated list of the columns in my db. Like this `BEDOK-20`,`BEDOK-22`.

My db is like this
[image]

My controller code i tried

```
    public function getNames(Request $request){
        $result =  DB::connection('mysql2')
                    ->table('xp_pn_resale')
                    ->select('town')
                    ->whereRaw(DB::raw("CONCAT(town, ' ', street_name,'',block,'')LIKE '%$request->projectname%' "))
                    ->limit($request->limit)   
                    ->get();
                    // ->toSql();

        return response()->json($result);            
    }
```

And i got response like this

```
"town": "BEDOK"
},
{
"town": "BEDOK"
},
{
"town": "BEDOK"
},
...
```

What I want is like this

```
[
"town": "BEDOK-44"
},
{
"town": "BEDOK-540"
},
{
"town": "BEDOK-702"
},
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to select like this:

```php
->selectRaw("CONCAT(town, '-', block) AS town")
```

Comment: I should replace the `select` with your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue before and I solved it with a DB::raw only, you can try changing your whereRaw method like this

```
->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(`town`, '-', `block`)", "LIKE", "%".$request->projectname."%"))
```